# Why are my methods apparently not accepting a value?

Tags: java, methods

I'm coding a Library program for my classroom, but I ran into an error quite immediately after compiling. The challenge for this program is that I need to use 3 files, only one of which (libraryRunner) actually has a Main in it. I'm trying to get both of the other method files (libraryCard and libraryBooks respectively) to work together.

I used Booleans before, and switched to Ints to see if that would fix it, but i get the same error. What's weird is that the program seems to compile, but the program just exits after the previously mentioned error.

Library Runner :

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class libraryRunner
{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      libraryCard Joseph = new libraryCard();

      Joseph.whichBook("Sing");
   }
}
```

What i'm using in Library Card :

```java
...
   public static String whichBook(String c)
   {
      if(libraryBooks.c == 1)
      {
         return("Sorry, it's already been checked out.");
      }
      else
      {
         return("Here's your book, " + c + "!");
      }
   }
}
```

What i'm using in Library Books:

```java
public class libraryBooks
{
   private static int hasBeenCheckedOut;

   public libraryBooks()
   {
      libraryBooks.Sing(0);
   }

   public static int Sing(int c)
   {
      hasBeenCheckedOut = c;
      return(hasBeenCheckedOut);
   }
...
```

From what even my teacher tells me, the program *should* in theory compile and run, telling the user that the book "Sing" is now theirs. But I only get this error :

----jGRASP exec: java libraryRunner
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: libraryCard.whichBook(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at libraryRunner.main(libraryRunner.java:8)

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: The error message shows that the actual code in the main method tries to call libraryCard.whichBook with an **array** or strings as argument. You have probably not recompiled your whole code. Also, you're completely disrespecting the Java naming conventions, and a constructor calling a static method and modifying a static field is really, really not a good idea. Naming a variable `c` is not either.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for helping, sorry for not respecting the names n' such. I only just learned how to make methods a month ago so i'm not the most experienced programmer :(

Comment: You don't need to be very experienced. Just mimic what all the existing classes do: all start with an uppercase letter, all their methods and variables start with a lowercase letter. You're doing the reverse, but sometimes not.